# make Jenkins ignore cmake errors

Tags: c++, cmake, jenkins

Is there a way to make the Jenkins CI server ignore certain errors?

In a project I need to run cmake several times to make it succeed (I cannot change that). In the first and second run errors might occur, which I would like to ignore. 
Is it possible to configure the build in jenkins in such a way?

Comment: You know this already it sounds like, but I'll re-iterate: something is wrong here, and you're trying to hack around it, making it _more_ wrong.

Comment: yeah, i agree. if you need to generate something before you build, you can add a build phase before any code is compiled, for example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on > In a project I need to run cmake several times to make it succeed (I cannot change that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with the others that it seems like there is a problem with your build process in general, there is a way to workaround it [until it is fixed].

For each cmake call, use a separate build step that executes a shell (or Windows batch file, depending on your environment).  For the first two, you should have two lines

```
cmake <....some stuff...>
exit 0
```

The first will execute your cmake.  The second sets the return value that Jenkins will look at.  Returning a 0 tells Jenkins that there were no failures.

For the last one, you don't want to the exit 0, since you want any errors caught.

Update: I ran into a situation where Jenkins would abort a shell script on the first line that returned non-zero.  The solution I found was actually pretty simple.  Put the "exit 0" on the same line as the command that caused the non-zero result.

```
cmake <....some stuf...> ; exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that is similar to the "solution" I found, thanks.
I know that it is not great to have the cmake the way it is, but as I said I cannot change the cmake scripts.

Comment: I have a similar problem and this doesn't work for me. Before exit 0 can be executed, there's already been stderr output and the jenkins job is halted/marked errorneous... Thoughs?

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel I've updated the answer with a solution that I found to work.

Comment: @jwernery adding || true instead of ; exit 0 also works for me :)